# NSDateFormatter not working to covert NSString to NSDate

Tags: nsdateformatter

I am using `NSDateFormatter` to get a date from an `NSString` I am confused as to why the following is not working:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: timeDateUpdated];
```

**myDate** remains nil and yet, as the image shows the **timeDateUpdated** appears to be of the correct format.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong format, use `HH` instead of `hh`.

The `h` directive is for hour in the am/pm format, will not work with `17`.

See this comprehensive date formatting [guide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

Comment: So simple - what a dope! Thanks

Comment: Don't worry, happens to me too with format strings :D